# Humanoids in seventh doctor and tenth doctor story

Tags: doctor-who

Are the Futurekind from the Tenth Doctor episode "Utopia" the same as the Haemovore from the Seventh Doctor episode "The Curse of Fenric?"

### The Curse of Fenric

In the serial, the ancient evil force Fenric uses the vampiric Haemovores, the descendants of humanity from the future, to attack a World War II naval base in England.

### Utopia

As they explore the planet Malcassairo, the Doctor, Jack, and the Doctor's companion Martha encounter Padra, a lone human running for his life from cannibalistic humanoids called the Futurekind.

They are both descendants of humanity

Comment: There are *lots* of descendants of humanity portrayed in Doctor Who. After they evacuated the Earth in the 29th century, we went all over the place.

Comment: Given the intended audience of the show, if they had intended the Futurekind to be the same as the Haemovores, they would have used the same name for them. On the other hand, if they did that they might have had to pay royalties to David Briggs, writer of The Curse of Fenric, like they do to (the estate of) Terry Nation whenever they use the Daleks.

Answer (score 2):

They have some thematic similarities but there is nothing to say they are the same. Over (what was then) 40 years of Doctor Who, it's inevitable that some concepts will turn up more than once. We have multiple explanations for the Big Bang, Atlantis, and the Loch Ness Monster. There are countless alien horrors buried in various catacombs. And there is more than one grim alternate future of the human species. In the absence of any positive reason to unify them (e.g. something shown on-screen or discussed by the creators) it makes more sense to treat them as distinct in-universe, even though they occupy a similar dramatic and conceptual space in their respective stories.

Some more detailed rationale for them not being the same:

1. They are future versions of humanity - but the Futurekind are from *much* further forward. In *The Curse of Fenric*, the Doctor describes the Haemovores as being from thousands of years in the future, after "half a million years of industrial progress". But *Utopia* takes place a hundred trillion years in the future, when even the stars have all gone out. In that story - and consistently with *Gridlock* in the same season, which is set five billion years in the future - the Doctor also says that over millions of years, humans try out various different forms but keep going back to the basic humanoid shape. So it is hard to see Haemovores as a consistent version of future-humanity over that stretch of time.
2. The Haemovores are from a version of the future scarred by pollution. That's not what is going on with the Futurekind, whose planet is desolate but not poisoned.
3. The Haemovores, as the name suggests, are vampiric. They consume blood, and are even repelled by faith in the manner of a classic vampire. They are an intelligent enemy who make plans and have lines of dialogue like "You know me?" and "My world is dead". While we don't see much of the Futurekind, what we do see has them attacking fairly mindlessly, with such classic lines as "Human!!" and "Make feast!" which are not suggestive of the same level of intelligence. They still want to eat people but are more direct in their approach.
4. Both species are involved with a temporal paradox orchestrated by a superior force. The Haemovores are manipulated by Fenric into trying to poison the Earth in 1943 and bring about their own evolution. Humans in the *Utopia* era are transformed into the Toclafane by the Master, then transported back to contemporary Earth, creating a bootstrap paradox. (These are strictly speaking *not* the Futurekind, who don't get on the ship to Utopia, but they are associated: the regular humans fear that the Futurekind represent their own destiny.) While these are somewhat similar happenings, trying to unify these to one narrative would create more questions than it answered. Both alternate-futures are also tidied away by the end of their respective stories.
5. Along those lines, the writer Russell T. Davies might well *avoid* reusing the Haemovores, as a Who-knowing audience might start asking "Where's Fenric, then? *Is* he the Master, or what?" and other distracting questions.
6. The bit when the possessed Judson orders the Haemovores to attack his nurse ("You've looked after me all these years. Almost a mother, treating me like a child, humiliating me.") is quite like the bit when the restored Yana-Master murders his assistant Chan-Tho (" Did you never think, all those years standing beside me, to ask about that watch? Never? Did you never once think, not ever, that you could set me free?"). But there is no sense in these being the same character. It's just a similarly sinister moment.